# Cinnamon - remember more recent files

Tags: javascript, applet, linux-mint, recent-file-list, cinnamon

I'm using *Linux Mint 17.1* with *Cinnamon 2.4.8*. There is nice feature in Cinnamon - **Remember recently accessed files**. So I can go to **Start Menu**, type partial name of the desired file and click on it to open. I've noticed that there are too few files remembered.

---

For example, I experimented with PDF files. Let call them `A.pdf`, `B.pdf`, `...` I double-clicked on `A.pdf`, `B.pdf`, `C.pdf`, `D.pdf` one by one in the file manager (it's *Nemo* which is default in Linux Mint Cinnamon Edition). And got the following list of recent files:

- `D.pdf`
- `C.pdf`
- `B.pdf`
- `A.pdf`

Then I opened `E.pdf`. And the list became:

- `E.pdf`
- `D.pdf`
- `C.pdf`
- `B.pdf`

But anyway the list of recent files is too short regardless of **Never forget old files** setting:

[image: Privacy window - Recent files settings.png]

I want more files in the list.

Yes, there are other files I worked with (the machine I've tested on is not virtual machine but real computer, so it's difficult to make "ideal" experiment only with PDFs). I suppose that the list size is much smaller than 999 entries for example. Perhaps this is why I see only 4 recent PDF files in the **Start Menu**.

---

I've tried to look into source code of Cinnamon (Git repo is about 11 Megabytes of source code, so I've only did `grep -i -R 'recent' Cinnamon`). And found out the following (let me focus on the most probable cases):

1. `cs_privacy.py` module ([definition of constant](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/blob/726443f76ce39246c71f70f454c3df0242e9620f/files/usr/lib/cinnamon-settings/modules/cs_privacy.py#L7) and [its usage](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/blob/726443f76ce39246c71f70f454c3df0242e9620f/files/usr/lib/cinnamon-settings/modules/cs_privacy.py#L55)). Perhaps, this module is responsible for managing dialog that was [depicted above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B94PB.png).
2. [Applet menu@cinnamon.org](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/blob/726443f76ce39246c71f70f454c3df0242e9620f/files/usr/share/cinnamon/applets/menu%40cinnamon.org/applet.js#L30). Seems that this applet is responsible for displaying **Start Menu**. Perhaps after increasing `MAX_RECENT_FILES` constant list of recent files will grow respectively.

I suspect second variant, e.g. **menu@cinnamon.org** applet. It's easy to change constant in the corresponding JavaScript file (it's stored as plain text). But the file is located in `/usr/share/cinnamon/applets/menu@cinnamon.org/applet.js`. So I afraid it will be overrode after running `apt-get upgrade`.

---

Is it possible to increase list of recently used files permanently in Cinnamon? Or I chose wrong direction of investigation?

Comment: Is this still looking for an answer? I see 20 recently used files with Cinnamon 4.0.10.